# How to select the email template from flow

Tags: apex, email, visual-workflow

I have created an email template using lightning email template builder and I want to use this template to send the users but I am unable to find any option to select created template in flow. If I try to use the Text template resource from flow its not aligning properly. I have lot of images in template. Is there any way to select the template from flow ? Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Have you created an email alert with this template and then using Flow Element: Email Alert?

Comment: I will not have control on Email addresses if I am going to use email alert, I needs to send different persons dynamically based on conditions, which is not possible in workflow email alert.